# Purging comments sets the Deletion User to the comment purger for previously-deleted comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Purge all comments marks the mod as the person who deleted, even if they were deleted by someone else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124782/purge-all-comments-marks-the-mod-as-the-person-who-deleted-even-if-they-were-de)

For reference, have a look here (admin only, sorry folks):

https://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/6985844/show-comments

The first four comments were deleted by Bill The Lizard.  I did a comments purge on the remaining comments.  Note that I am now listed as the deletion user for the original four (already deleted) comments.

Comment: In addition, if a comment is deleted after flagging it as offensive, the person who flagged it is listed as the one who deleted it, instead of Community (which is how it normally is for flagged posts).