# Purge all comments marks the mod as the person who deleted, even if they were deleted by someone else

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools, deleted-comments

Let's say that a question has some deleted comments. Now, if I look at the deleted comments, they show the person who deleted the comment.

[image]

Now if I go in and choose purge all comments, it marks even the previously deleted comments, as deleted by me.

[image]

Though it's a minor thing, this behaviour kinda makes it tough to investigate he-said-she-said behaviour.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, it'll no longer overwrite deletion dates/users if they already exist.

Comment: Better [status-completed] this one too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101782 :P